# Session ID and Token from PHP to Javascript to PHP (xmlHTTPRequest)

Tags: php, javascript, sessionid

I am currently working on a upload system using Javascript to send the file via xmlhttprequest, wich works just fine. Now i want to store the file information inside a database, together with the information about the uploader. 
The user has to log in, to upload a file. Therefore i am storing all logged in members in a own table (id, user_id, session_id, token).

Now my problem is that i somehow have to determine the username for the uploader information.
My current solution is something like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
 fd.append("user", {{username}});
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("POST", "/upload/local/handleUpload.php");
 xhr.send(fd);
```

I am using twig template system to render the template files ({{username}} is the username send by the php script)

Now i understand that the username could easily be changed to something else. This is why i want to make sure that there is a user with this username and possibly this session_id in the "logged_in" table.

My first approach would be to just append the current session_id of the user and send it.

```
fd.append("session_id", {{session_id}});
```

But here is my question: Is this a "secure" way of doing this? Or how am i supposed to handle this?
I appreciate every help i can get!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to send the session id as the session cookie will be sent anyway. To make sure the user exists, `handleUpload.php` has to check the session against your database table.

Comment: Alright. I wasnt quite sure if the handleUpload.php script would be able to get the current session_id of this user, because it is called via xmlhttprequest.